# How do smartphones decide whether a phone call is spam or not?

Tags: spam

Like everyone else, I'm receiving spam calls. With my current job, most communication goes over the Internet (online meetings, chats, etc.) so in my case, it's nearly only spam.

What I'm wondering is how can the phone decide whether a call is a spam call? It can't be based on the phone number since 99% of the time (it seems) those are spoofed. Once in a while, I get calls from people who received a spam call with my phone number spoofed.

I've heard a year or so ago that the TELCO were going to implement a system to help verify phone numbers, but I've not seen anything more than that.

Comment: Smartphones don't decide. The phone app or equivalent connect to a server (~ online services) that compare the number(s) with a database of known spam numbers. If found, it is relayed back to the smartphone(s) and displayed as spam on your screen.

Comment: For example: Google's own [Phone app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.dialer&hl=en&gl=US) and [its caller ID & spam protection](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/3459196)

Comment: @AndrewT. It sounds like the Spam Detection is based on the caller ID which is what's getting spoofed. I thought that the TELCO were working on a system to detect the spoofing...